# Resolve service in Program.cs .net 7 Asp.net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-7.0

In .net 6 Asp.net Core `Startup.cs` I have this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DbSeeder dataSeeder)
{
    dataSeeder.Seed();
```

here the `DbSeeder` is resolved because I've added it as a parameter to the `Configure` method.

How would I do the same (resolve a service) in .net 7 if I choose to skip the `Startup.cs` and have all the configuration in `Program.cs` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways.  This is how I do it.

I have a static class for all my configuration stuff - in this case to add some test data to a InMemory test database

```cs
public static class WeatherAppDataServices
{
    // extension method for IServiceCollection 
    public static void AddAppServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // define your specific services
        services.AddScoped<WeatherForecastService>();
    }

    //.... other config stuff

    public static void AddTestData(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var factory = provider.GetService<IDbContextFactory<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>>();

        if (factory is not null)
            // do your seeding
            // this one is mine
            WeatherTestDataProvider.Instance().LoadDbContext<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>(factory);
    }
}
```

And my Program:

```cs
// Add services to the container.
{
    var Services = builder.Services;
    {
        Services.AddRazorPages();
        Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        Services.AddAuthentication();
        Services.AddAuthorization();

        // this is where my specific app services get added
        Services.AddAppServices();

        Services.AddWeatherAppServerDataServices<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>(options
            => options.UseInMemoryDatabase($"WeatherDatabase-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}"));
      /....
    }
}

var app = builder.Build();

// you now have a `WebApplication` instance and can get the services manually
// I Add the test data to the In Memory Db here
WeatherAppDataServices.AddTestData(app.Services);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
/....
```

Comment: think a shorter answer would be

 `var app = builder.Build(); 
var neededServ = app.Services.GetService<MyService>();`